# Can't convert a string to an integer

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, string, integer

I'm creating dynamically some tags like this:

```
$('#marker').before('<div class ="file_up" id="bloc_3"></div>');
```

Then later, I get the number from the id:

```
$('.file_up').live("click",function() 
{
    var address  = $(this).att('id');
    var substr  = address.split("_");
    var suffix = substr.pop("_");

    $.ajax({
        url: "xxxx.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: "suff="+parseInt(suffix),
        cache: false,
        success: function (res){ alert(res);}
    })

}
```

Then, in the php file, I do something like this:

```
<?php

$suff= intval($_POST['suff']);
$x=4;
echo $suff+$x;

?>
```

Whatever I try, instead of getting a sum of 7, I get a concatenation of two strings like this: "34".

Don't know what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried casting `$suff` to an integer like so: `$suff = (int)$_POST['suff']`

Comment: Is this actually the code that you're using?

Comment: i wasn't aware that `pop()` took any parameters?

Comment: Your question is all about the PHP? So please remove the JS parts (and tags), and rather show us the request object than how you generated it.

Comment: unrelated: don't split the id but instead just store id as data-id attribute e.g. `<div id="bloc_3" data-id="3"></div>`
and then
`var id = parseInt($(this).attr('data-id'))`

Comment: @AnuragUniyal jQuery (1.7+?) allows the use of `$(this).data('id');`

Comment: There's no way that `$suff+$x` can do concatenation; PHP uses `.` for concatenation, not `+`.

Comment: I agree with @Barmar, better make sure you are sending 3, not 30.

Comment: I don't know why I can only send one comment to all of you so... No it's not only about php, as it could be anywhere as far as I know. I don't know why you assume it's a php thing as the variable is created and displayed through js. No I don't send 30, because displayed alone it is 3 and 4 and displayed together, it's 34. Yes, I tried (int)*variable with no success. No it's not the code I'm using, juste the parts I wanted you to see (I feel like you are mocking me somehow). Yes, the "data-id" seems a good way to go. Thank you.

Comment: So try it with the php code that you posted, maybe the error is somewhere in the part that you don't want to show.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 $suff = (int) $_POST['suff'];
 $x = 4;
 echo $suff + $x;
```

Comment: `var_dump(intval("3"));` is `int(3)` -- integer 3. Problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Yes I tried this among other things (like multiply the variable by one to force casting as I read somewhere around here).I believe the data-id is the way to go. I will try that and see what happens then.

Comment: Since all post variables are sent as text, and you are getting a "3" on the server, the problem is not javascript/html related and must be a php problem.